# After Pie upgrade, lock screen is not hiding all sensitive content

Tags: lock-screens, 9.0-pie

I recently upgraded my Pixel 2 from Android Oreo to Pie. I have "Security & location" -> "Lock screen preferences" set to "Hide sensitive content".

Ever since the upgrade, when I receive an email while my phone is locked, in addition to the email notification icon, it also displays my email address under it for a short while (Maybe 60 seconds.) Even after it goes away, if I double tap the screen or press the power button, it shows my email address again on the screen; note the phone is still locked at this point. (I'm fairly certain that) prior to the upgrade only the email icon was shown without also displaying my email address while the phone is locked.

I am using the standard Gmail app with multiple email addresses configured. I consider my email address(es) to be sensitive information and don't want them to be displayed on my locked phone.

Is this a new bug (or strange feature), or is it configurable? Or am I completely mistaken and it's always been this way?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug, your email address is showing due to multiple email configurations u have made. However your point is valid that your email address is a sensitive information, u can try sending feedback to google by reviewing Gmail on Playstore.

Comment: I had multiple emails configured before the update too, and AFAIK it didn't start displaying the email until after the upgrade...

Comment: i experienced email shown in sensitive content on all my devices, they have android M, O and P.

Comment: Interesting - it's possible it's always been like that, though I'm surprised I never noticed until now.

Comment: i never had sensitive info hidden, i saw ur question and checked..